# How to use multiple text values using sas prompt

Tags: sas, prompt, enterprise-guide

I am trying to create a prompt which allows to user to enter multiple values from a list.   I have used Prompt Type as **Text**.
Method of populating the prompt : **User select values from static list**
Number of values : **Multiple Values** [image: prompt]

I have kept the name of my prompt as Products. Basically I want to have a macro which has values such as "product 1","product 2", Product 3", "product 4" separated by commas.

[image: Comma separated list]

When I try and resolve the products macro no matter how many products I select in the prompt it always resolves the first product. Here it is always resolving only Loan as the resolution to the products macro.   I want all the products in that I select through prompt to come in the macro **product**. Example ("loan","Overdraft","RCF") Please suggest what to do in this case

Comment: You should see a series of macro variable generated rather than a single macro variable with a list of values.

Comment: Unless it has changed in the last three years this blog post had an excellent explanation. http://bi-notes.com/2013/08/sas-stored-process-taming-selection-list-prompts/

Comment: Hi Joe, my apologies it was  mistake from my end. I have redone it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a prompt, "Color", with the six colors of the rainbow, with the settings like you describe (and "use throughout project").

Then I attached it to the following program:

```
%put _global_;
```

And what I see is this;

```
8          %LET Color0 = 4;
9          %LET Color2 = Red;
10         %LET Color3 = Yellow;
11         %LET Color4 = Orange;
12         %LET Color1 = Blue;
13         %LET Color_count = 4;
14         %LET Color = Blue;
```

This is how multiple value prompts work: they put the first selection in `&prompt`, then put the number of selected items in `&prompt0`, and then put the selected items in `&prompt1-&&prompt&prompt0`. You can then use them in a number of ways.  You can

```
%do i = 1 %to &color0.;
  %put &&color&i.;
%end;
```

For example.

Comment: Does it create the COLOR0 macro value when only 1 entry is selected? What about when none are selected? It didn't used to.  I think it used to just make `COLOR_COUNT=0` and not make `COLOR` at all when none were selected.

Answer (score 0):

..a few years later (and perhaps a change in SAS 9.4), but there are other factors to consider.
If you provide an "(all possible values)" option, and the user makes this selection, then

- &PromptValue = *ALL_VALUES*
- &Prompt_Count = 1
- &Prompt0 = listcount - 1
- &Prompt1 .. PromptX contain one item from the list

..forcing you to concatenate them using a micro-macro like unto thusly (assembling academic terms FL, WN, SP, SM):

```
%MACRO GetPrompt;
    %IF "&Terms" = "_ALL_VALUES_" %THEN %DO;
        %LET Terms = %sysfunc(catx(|, &Terms1, &Terms2, &Terms3, &Terms4));
    %END;
    %ELSE %DO;
        %DO inx = 2 %TO &TERMS_COUNT;
            %LET Terms = %sysfunc(catx(|, &Terms, &&Terms&inx));
        %END;
    %END;
%MEND GetTerms;
```